# Swift3: Crash on presenting pop over

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipopover, uimodalpresentationstyle

```
let obj = MainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeVC") as! SomeVC
obj.delegate = self

obj.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
self.present(obj, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On setting up breakpoints, debugger goes good till last line. After that, it directly goes to `AppDelegate` class first line.

I have set exception break point properly. Where I might be making a mistake? Is it related to `sourceView` for `popoverPresentationController`? I am not sure.

What I want to do is set up the `popoverPresentationController` in center. Any help?

**EDIT:**
I added the `sourceView` to the code like following & now it's working:

```
obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 1, height: 1)
```

However, it's not in the center of the screen. Putting screen shot for reference. How do I make it to the center and remove the direction arrow?

[image]

Comment: Any crash reports?

Comment: In console, none. Except: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: show teh full crash report

Comment: put logs in SomeVC's view life cycle methods and check whether that view presenting or not and try commenting the line 'obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect'

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Not able to get anything related to crash except the above mentioned exception. Exception break point is also set. But, it's not letting me know on which line it's crashing.

Comment: then enable the zombies and check once

Comment: @raki `viewDidLoad` got printed in console. `viewWillAppear` didn't.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Enabled zombies. How to trace now?

Comment: @sweta.me - run once  it automtcailly thorw the exception if it is crash

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik same exception. No additional information. `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: @sweta.me - really amazing can you attach ur project

Comment: @sweta.me so something is wrong in your SomeVC, once check the code by putting break points in that class starting from viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Really, can't. Quite large project and confidential, too.

Comment: Just to narrow down the problem if it is with your ViewController or presenting a popover, can you please try presenting UIAlertView/UIAlertViewController at the same point you are presenting pop over ?

Comment: Just changing `sourceRect` to `sourceView` like: `obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view` makes it run fine. But, I want the pop-over to appear in center

Comment: What if you write this? `obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.view.bounds.midY, width: 1, height: 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `sourceView` in conjunction with `sourceRect` to provide anchor point for pop over, like following:

```
obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 1, height: 1)
```

Also, If you don't want the anchor point arrow to be there, then use:

```
obj.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)
```

It will make your pop over appear in center with no arrow/anchor point.

Answer (score 2):

After doing the following code changes I was able to make it work.

```
let obj = MainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeVC") as! SomeVC
obj.delegate = self

obj.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
obj.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)
obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
obj.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 1, height: 1)
self.present(obj, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thank You all for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:
    let obj = MainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeVC") as! SomeVC
    obj.delegate = self
    obj.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.navigationController?.present(obj, animated: false, completion: {
                            })
```

Comment: This is not crashing but, the pop over is fullscreen and I want it to be 682 x 450 in size. So, kind of not working.

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible. Try changing the constraints of objViewcontroller so that it is presented to the required dimension.